# How does Salesforce Calculates Fiscal Periods?

Tags: datetime, timezone, closedate

We have offices around the globe (from India to San Francisco).

Now I am told, that our West coast users, get their date reset at midday. As weird as it sounds to me, I am interested to know: How does SF calculates the Date time? and especially the Close Date of an oppty?

For example:  If my India user will close an oppty on 31/12, early in his morning, will reports run in SF show: 31/12 ? or 30/12 (current date)

The same - If my SF user closes a deal late on 31/12 - will that show on reports as 1/1 (next year) for India users? since the oppty was closed on Indian time zone - it's considered next year already?

-- I am not referring to any APEX issues in this q

Answer (score 3):

By default SF consider UTC timezone.And run its process based on this. but on user's record view or report view It consider their timezone.

So if Indian user close on 31/12 morning It will display It is as 31/12.

Same with other case.

But if you use Datetime class in apex then Salesforce consider Organization Timezone. So if your org Timezone is different then User timezone that will also affect.

Comment: If my Indian user closes on 31/12 - will that show as 31/12 for my SF user? seems very complicated rendering. It's not render for user, it's rendered based on owner?

Comment: Yes. It is display same. Some part is complicated.

Comment: Reading further your answer: If my US employee will set the close date to 31/12, my India user will see it 1/1 - since the date is stored in UTC, and rendered to India time. unless: close date only stores the actual/current date of user.